# After Open Page..Loop Animation

Tags: javascript

I have this and I need that after end of animation (addClass and removeClass) it will play again. In some intervals. Can you help

```
setTimeout(function loopLight() {
    $('.light.animation .bulp').addClass('light-uno-start');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.light.animation .bulp').addClass('light-uno-middle');
        setTimeout(function () {
          $('.light.animation .bulp').addClass('light-uno-end');
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('.light.animation .bulp').removeClass('light-uno-start').removeClass('light-uno-middle').removeClass('light-uno-end');
            },65);
        }, 6000);
      }, 560);
  },500
);


let loopLight = setInterval(function (){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
     }, 500);
   }, 500);
```

Comment: Can you show us the matching html, css and specify 'this', 'that' and 'some'?